# Jeep CanBus Lock/Unlock new duplicate door latch

Tags: locks, door, can-bus, latch

I have an 07 Jeep Grand Cherokee CRD. I have a rear bumper mounted tire carrier that I would like to repurpose an extra door latch to secure the tire carrier closed. Is it possible to piggy back on the existing CanBus network to get this extra latch/lock to lock and unlock at the same time as the normal doors?

I am expecting that if I purchase an additional door lock and splice it into an original door lock power connector, that the lock will either cause a conflict and weird errors or will function as though the lock were factory installed.

Are there search terms or other pieces of information that I could use to research this topic further? I am very unfamiliar with how CanBus functions.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, you won't need to do anything with the CANBus network. The connection using your existing door lock wiring should be sufficient. In most every vehicle, the Body Control Module (BCM or whatever the manufacturer wants to call them) does the work by applying power correctly to the right circuits (or causing it to be applied by closing relays). The locks themselves take no direction through the CANBus. If you are connecting to wiring which is already being activated by the BCM, it should activate the solenoid which will lock/unlock what you're trying to install.

Comment: Thank you, that is just the information I needed to justify purchasing the latch.